# Type of variable for an array of objects

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm confused with the following example taken from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/)

```
// pointer to classes example
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CRectangle {
    int width, height;
  public:
    void set_values (int, int);
    int area (void) {return (width * height);}
};

void CRectangle::set_values (int a, int b) {
  width = a;
  height = b;
}

int main () {
  CRectangle a, *b, *c;
  CRectangle * d = new CRectangle[2];
  b= new CRectangle;
  c= &a;
  a.set_values (1,2);
  b->set_values (3,4);
  d->set_values (5,6);
  d[1].set_values (7,8);
  cout << "a area: " << a.area() << endl;
  cout << "*b area: " << b->area() << endl;
  cout << "*c area: " << c->area() << endl;
  cout << "d[0] area: " << d[0].area() << endl;
  cout << "d[1] area: " << d[1].area() << endl;
  delete[] d;
  delete b;
  return 0;
}
```

I was thinking about why `d[0].area()` is legal as opposed to `d[0]->area()` and this lead me to the deceleration of `d` where `CRectangle * d = new CRectangle[2];`. Isn't there two levels of indirection so shouldn't `d` be declared with `CRectangle ** d` since new returns a pointer and it's a pointer to a pointer since it's an array (hence the []). In other words doesn't `**=*[]`?

Comment: No, **ARRAYS ARE NOT POINTERS!**

Comment: Don't use cplusplus.com, use [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/)

Comment: [Everything you need to know about arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Comment: Eww, the page does one on dynamically allocating members, but fails to even mention the Rule of Three or RAII.

Comment: @antiduh, Part of the reason I particularly like C# and D. No dumb C compatibility to worry about.

Comment: @antiduh "yet i just assigned an array allocated on the heap to a pointer variable" no, you didn't. There are *pointer to array* s in C++, but the type of the expression `new type[number]` is explicitly a pointer to the initial element of the array as per [expr.new]/5. I agree the syntax doesn't reflect this in an obvious way.

Answer (score 2):

`CRectangle * d = new CRectangle[2];` declares `d` as a pointer to `CRectangle` and initializes it to point to the first object of an array containing two `CRectangle` objects. So `d[0]`, has type `CRectangle`, *not* a pointer to `CRectangle`. This is why using the dot operator (.) is legal.

Comment: Very pedantic: as an object is a region of storage, I think the phrase *element of an array* is slightly better than *object of an array*. The Standard uses the phrase "initial element" in [expr.new]/5.

Comment: @DyP Hopefully my current edit better emphasizes that I'm referring to  the type of `d[0]` which was my initial intent in using the word "object" in the OO sense.

Comment: You're answer is fine and was fine, I just made a very pedantic remark ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

For:

```
CRectangle *d = new CRectangle[2];
```

Is (roughly) equivalent to (never, ever, ever do this; just use new):

```
CRectangle *d = (CRectangle*)malloc(2*sizeof(CRectangle));
... plus some default construction ...
```

d is a pointer.
d[0] is not a pointer, it is the value at the array index 0.

d[n] is shorthand for `*(d + n)` which is the value (hence the dereference *) at location 'n' in the array d. The return value of `new CRectangle[2]` is `CRectangle*`.

Arrays are stored in memory like:

```
       d[0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] ...
Value    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H  ... 
offset:  0  +1  +2  +3  +4  +5  ( x sizeof(CRectangle) of course)...
```

Comment: Except I believe that `malloc` is UB.

Comment: new is equivalent to malloc and a constructor call -- In this case, the default constructor.

Comment: @Joel, But you can't `malloc` a non-POD type (or can, but shouldn't unless you like having unpredictable code).

Comment: Ah, true... I keep forgetting how much C++ really does for me in the background haha

Comment: @chris "you can't `malloc` a non-POD type" What about `CRectangle *d = new( malloc(2*CRectangle) ) CRectangle;`? (it lacks the basic exception guarantee, though)

Comment: @chris, you are correct, but it's because of the constructor call.